# MaybeT monad transformer changing Writer to WriterT

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I am trying to learn monad transformers, and have problems to find an explanation of one issue.

Say, I create a writer (in ghci) like this:

```
let w =  writer (Just "value", ["log"]) :: Writer [String] (Maybe String)
```

And now I want to wrap it in the `MaybeT` monad transformer. `MaybeT` constructor has the following type:

```
:t MaybeT
m (Maybe a) -> MaybeT m a
```

And, based on this, the result of calling `MaybeT` with `w` should have the type:

```
MaybeT (Writer [String]) String
```

But it it does not:

```
let mt = MaybeT w
:t mt
MaybeT (WriterT [String] Data.Functor.Identity.Identity) String
```

My question is, why does ghci substitute `Writer [String]` to `WriterT [String] Identity`? I don't understand it at all, but I have a strong feeling I'm missing something here.

Comment: It's the same thing: `Writer a` is a type synonym of `WriterT a Identity`.

Comment: In old versions of the libraries you'd have obtained the result you expected. However new versions use monad transformers "all the way down" and monads like `Reader` and `Writer` are defined using the corresponding transformer (`ReaderT` and `WriterT`) and exploiting the `Identity` monad (which "does nothing"). `Reader` is just a type synonym. When unifying those types the synonym is expanded and you see the actual type.

Comment: `writer` is actually: `writer :: Monad m => (a, w) -> WriterT w m a` and `Writer w a = WriterT w Identity a` -  in your case `m = Identity`, `a = Maybe String` and `w = [String]` - the last argument (here `a`) *curried* away in the other comments and for `MaybeT` (because the first component of `MaybeT` should have kind `* -> *`) (PS: *curried* is not really the [right concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion) here but I hope you understand what I'm saying)

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now.

Comment: @Carsten: Depends. If you're using the monad transformer library (mtl),  `Control.Monad.Writer.writer` is `MonadWriter w m => (a, w) -> m a`, whereas your type stems from `Control.Monad.Trans.Writer` from `transformer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a community-wiki answer summarizing the point of the comments:

It's the same thing: `Writer a` is a type synonym of `WriterT a Identity`. Furthermore, `writer` is actually: `writer :: Monad m => (a, w) -> WriterT w m a`. In your case `m` = `Identity`, `a` = `Maybe String` and `w` = `[String]`.